# Auto-Save File while running a loop

Tags: vba, excel, autosave

i have a long list of local webpages which are to be parsed by a macro in Excel 2013. I was wondering if there is any way to automatically save the file every 5 minutes or so while looping through these files (>9000 local .HTM files).

Here is some code:

```
Sub ImportFromWebPages()

'declare here some global variables

For startnumber = 1 to 9126

    'parse the .HTM files and extract the needed data
    'while running this loop (which will take some days to finish) 
    'Excel should save the file every 5 or 10 minutes.

Next startnumber
End Sub
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You should show your full code - `while running this loop (which will take some days to finish)`. That is extreme!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be easier to save after a certain numbers of files, say 5 for example. Please excuse my pseudocode:

```
Sub ImportFromWebPages()

    'declare here some global variables

    For startnumber = 1 to 9126

       'parse the .HTM files and extract the needed data
       'while running this loop (which will take some days to finish) 
       'Excel should save the file every 5 or 10 minutes.

        If startnumber Mod 5 = 0 Then

            ActiveWorkbook.Save

        End If

    Next startnumber
End Sub
```

Please see the following links for more on [Mod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz(VS.80).aspx) and [ActiveWorkbook.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585.aspx).

Comment: or, check out the =Now() function to incorporate time into the loop

Comment: thank you. That works very well for my situation as well.